# basic nodejs and express server setup not working

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

This should be very simple, steps I took:
1)used vue cli3 to create vue project (that worked fine).
2)created a server folder on the root level
3)created an index.js file 
4)created api/routes/users.js
I am getting in the browser at `http://localhost:4000/api/add` Cannot GET api/add.
Here is my index file:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const users = require('./api/routes/users');
app.use('api/add', users);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...` ));
```

Below this is my users.js file:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Here is what my package JSON looks like, not sure if this somehow creates problems since I first made the frontend and then started the backend.

```
{
  "name": "fastpo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.11",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.22",
    "vue-compose": "^0.7.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.4.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? ...

Comment: I clarified the issue

Comment: I'm assuming you just accidentally missed the `const express = require('express')` from users.js only here otherwise it's not successfully requiring that. Try preprending `/` here `app.use('/api/add'`

Comment: Also below your routes add a 404 catch e.g. `app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({ status: 404, code: 'NotFound' });
  next();
});`

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add "/" here before `api`: `app.use('api/add', users);`
should be `app.use('/api/add', users)`